# list of dictionaries into data frame columns

Tags: python, json, list

I have a column in a `DataFrame` that contains JSON strings, each representing a list of dictionaries:

```
    id Number  Type  Class Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                datiles
0  292      C     1      2    A  [{"did":{"id":"3","num":1},"NId":"a1,b1,c1","Att":null,"isnull":false,"number":"M90","label":[{"title":"Dear","Info":{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}},{"title":"Dear","Info":{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}}],"codes":[],"rule":null}]
1  293      C     1      2    A  [{"did":{"id":"3","num":1},"NId":"a1,b1,c1","Att":null,"isnull":false,"number":"M90","label":[{"title":"Dear","Info":{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}},{"title":"Dear","Info":{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}}],"codes":[],"rule":null}]
```

I want to convert each row in datiles column to rows and columns and join them with the original data frame as shown on the sample below:

```
       id     Number       Type     Class      Name            did                NId        Att  ..... .... label ........
      0292           C          1          2        A     {"id":"3","num":1}    a1,b1,c1    null    [{"title":"Dear","Info"{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}},{"title":"Dear","Info":{"Id":null,"id2":2,"Name":"x"}}]
```

I have done this as I need but I don't know how to join it with the original data frame since I don't have a key between them:

```
df['datiles']=data['datiles'].apply(json.loads)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([])

for x in df['datiles'].values.tolist():
    df2 = df2 .append(pd.DataFrame(x))
display(df2)
```

How can I split the column and join at the same time?
I have tried to use json_normalize but I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Also, I have seen those posts but does not work, may that because of the list structure

[How to convert python JSON rows to dataframe columns without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240520/how-to-convert-python-json-rows-to-dataframe-columns-without-looping)

[Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

[How to split a list of dictionaries into multiple columns keeping the same index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604212/how-to-split-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-multiple-columns-keeping-the-same-index)

Comment: there are typos in your copy of the first dataframe. `"Info"{"Id":null,...` is not a `dict` nor is it valid JSON. Is that column `datiles` really containing `dict`s? I doubt it, looks more like JSON strings to me (modulo the typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of your `df` and explicitly set it to your new `DataFrame` to join with, like that:

```
df['datiles'] = df['datiles'].apply(json.loads).apply(pd.DataFrame)
out = df.drop('datiles', axis=1).join(
    pd.concat(df['datiles'].values, keys=df.index).droplevel(1))
```

**Explanation**

1. The first line does a double `apply`: `json.loads` (as you had figured out) and `pd.DataFrame` (that you had figured out too, but here we do it in an `apply` instead of a loop).
2. The second line concats all those `DataFrames` inside `df['datiles']`, but uses the index of `df` itself as keys. The result is a `MultiIndex`, with possibly several rows for a given key (if the original `datiles` JSON string was a list of more than 1 element). In any case, we drop that second level. Then `join` does its usual thing (on indexes).

**Example**

The setup is a bit verbose for a SO answer (I wish we had an `expand` or `fold` macro), so I pasted it in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0dtLbDeL).

The point is, the first `datiles` is a JSON list of two elements, just to exercise the logic above. Aside from that, it's the same content as per the OP.

**Output**

```
    id Number  Type  Class Name                    did       NId   Att  \
0  292      C     1      2    A  {'id': '1', 'num': 1}  a1,b1,c1  None   
0  292      C     1      2    A  {'id': '2', 'num': 1}  a1,b1,c1  None   
1  293      C     1      2    A  {'id': '3', 'num': 1}  a1,b1,c1  None   

   isnull number                                              label codes  \
0   False    M90  [{'title': 'Dear', 'Info': {'Id': None, 'id2':...    []   
0   False    M90  [{'title': 'Dear', 'Info': {'Id': None, 'id2':...    []   
1   False    M90  [{'title': 'Dear', 'Info': {'Id': None, 'id2':...    []   

   rule  
0  None  
0  None  
1  None
```